# I have visual studio 2012. I want to develop a windows 10 app. Is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows

I have visual studio 2012.

I want to develop a windows 10 app.

Is it possible?

Comment: Slight tangent but, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is free and basically the same as the Pro edition, why don't you get that?

Answer (score 1):

Developing Windows 10 Apps on visual studio 2012 is not possible. Visual Studio 2012 was used to develop Windows Phone 7 and 7.1 Apps.

Please upgrade your OS to **Windows 10** . Install a free version of **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.**
Now you have all the tools to develop UWP Apps